# Problems installing RMagick-gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, stdint

I've been plowing through tutorials all day trying to install RMagick, and have gotten pretty far now I reckon, but have stumbled apon an error that I really don't know how to solve, nor get any useful info on.

When I try to install the gem, I get this message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
**checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed *****
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
 from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

---

I suppose that the part in bold is the important part, and I've done some research and have understood that stdint.h is some sort of header, but I don't know how to install it.

I also checked in the mkmf.log file which gave me this easy to read bit of info :

checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

---

```
"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby192/lib -L.    -lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11  -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-missing-field-initializers"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Big thanks in advance for any help!

Regards, Emil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by running 'apt-get install libmagick9-dev' which installs ImageMagicks devkit.

Comment: what is the equivalent for windows?

Comment: Sorry, never got it working for windows ... Tried for a whole week without succeding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

It works for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows? If you are, chances are, as ur log said, you need to install http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167 <-- the development kit since some commands for compiling doesn't exist...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kasumi. I am on Windows, and have already installed the devkit.

Comment: Sorry, I overlook this, you are not installing the correct version of rmagick... windows has a seperate gem rmagick-win32, and note the it needs a very specific version of Image Magick that comes with the source zip file http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=12

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can confirm, this error happens even if you have the devkit installed

Comment: Hey there Kasumi, I know it's been like, three years, but I am still having the same problem!  I got rmagick-win32 to install, and even show up in my installed gems (as rmagick), BUT I can't get it to include as a gem

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this, but do you have more information on what is the problem when you include it?